# Group Header position for Collectionview stays on the left

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, maui, collectionview

Currently setting the Header or Group header of a horizontal collectionview places the header on the left of the collection, which doesnt look good. I need the header to be displayed above the horizontal collection, but the default behavior is to be displayed on top of the collection only if the collectionview is in vertical orientation. Is there a way to implement it for horizontal collection.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a greater control over the position of the group headers for `CollectionView` like displaying group headers above (or below) the group items for **horizontal** orientation.

This is a feature request that is tracked in this [headers option for CollectionView with greater control over group header position](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12209). You can follow up there.